# Trouble altering a string in a variable with sed

Tags: bash, variables, replace, sed

I'm trying to get sed to update a variable in a bash script. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
myword="this is a test"
echo $myword
this is a test
```

Swap a test for working

```
$myword | sed 's/a test/working'
echo $myword
this is working
```

Comment: try myword = cat $myword | sed ...

Comment: @AmirAfghani You don't `cat` variables - you `echo` them...

Comment: twalberg, i haven't had my coffee yet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate your regular expression:

```
myword="this is a test"
myword=`echo $myword | sed 's/a test/working/'`
echo $myword

-> this is working
```

Also, you never reassigned the output back to the `myword` var.

Comment: don't you need to perform the assignment back into myword?

Answer (score 1):

Why go through the trouble of using `sed`. You can use bash string functions.

```
$ echo $myword
this is a test
$ echo ${myword/a test/working}
this is working
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you don't need `sed` for this task:

```
$ myword="this is a test"
$ myword=${myword/a test/working/'}
$ echo $myword
this is working
```

Post your actual use case if you cannot adapt this solution.